# WSO2 P.PaaS : Access APIM

Tags: wso2, paas, api-manager

Am new to WSO2. I have installed P.PaaS. How do I access APIM? Can you show me an example, please?

*using phone. Pardon brevity.*

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to install WSO2 Private PaaS to have API Manager. From WSO2 site, you can [download stand-alone API Manager](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/) or [use the hosted version - WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud).

Once you are familiar with API Manager or API Cloud, if you do decide that you want to spawn it within Private PaaS, you can [follow this document to locate the corresponding cartridge and subscribe to it](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Subscription+Management).

Comment: Ok. During P.PaaS installation, a prompt came up to know if APIM is to be installed. I entered yes. So, where did this installation go?

Comment: The API Manager is installed/enabled as a service which you can use. When you deploy those services (APIM in your case) there will be a number of instances on the IaaS you configured, which will autoscale according to the parameters you defined.

Comment: @Chamila, how do I access through APIM console? I have an API developed with proprietary source code. It is hosted on its own IaaS instance. How do I register it with APIM?

Comment: IMO as the first step, you're better off using the WSO2 API Cloud to register your API and have a feel of how APIM operates. You can find video tutorials on how to register, and subscribe to your APIs on the home page when you follow the link this answer has provided.

Comment: @Chamila, That worked. I want to replicate the same with P.PaaS.

Comment: In that case @Depository's answer below will guide you through how to setup PPaaS. When PPaaS setup is complete Step 4 and 5 will give you an idea on how to access services deployed on PPaaS.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting started with WSO2 Private PaaS, it is worth to watch these well-organized, 6-steps video tutorials on "Getting Started With WSO2 Private PaaS". After watching these, you will have a basic understanding, from there you can move forward without any issues.

Step 0 -  [Finding the Documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTVQ80F4rdk)

Step 1 - [Provisioning an EC2 Instance from WSO2 Private PaaS AMI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cfBSvHsR2Q)

Step 2 - [Provisioning the WSO2 Private Platform as a Service Environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg94PUiOd1g)

Step 3 - [Configuring Private Platform as a Service with Tenants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs2euQJFFGI)

Step 4 - [Provisioning Application Platform Services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngdhoxBjpZI)

Step 5 - [Deploying a Web Application on a Private Platform as a Service Environment running on Amazon EC2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4FxTUs966Y)

Comment: It does not help, sorry. I was done till Step 4 even before I posted this question. I realized that, Step 4 is not applicable to me because, the web app that I have to deploy is proprietary; therefore, cannot be hosted on a public repository. I tried replicating the same with WSO2 APIM GitHub URL. I got an error around 'cartridge [publisher]'.